# how do i convert int64 column to datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with column "time" which looks like:

```
array([43390, 43599, 43605, 43329, 43330, 43604, 43601, 43332, 43602,....43505], dtype=int64)
```

How do i get this into date time format? I have already tried

```
t_data["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(t_data["DATE"].astype(str).str.zfill(6), format='%H%M%S').dt.time
```

but causes error

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0

Comment: First element with `zfill` will return `043390`; what is the expected output? 4H 33M 90S? or 4H 34M 30S?

Answer (score 1):

The array of integers looks like dates that were extracted from Excel.  Each represents the days after the base_date (on/about 1901-01-01).

Here is a way to convert to dates in pandas:

```
date_offsets = [43390, 43599, 43605, 43329, 43330, 43604, 43601, 43332, 43602]
base_date = pd.Timestamp('1901-01-01')  # check this!
dates = [
    base_date + pd.DateOffset(date_offset) 
    for date_offset in date_offsets
]

print(dates[0:5])

[Timestamp('2019-10-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-05-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-05-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-08-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-08-20 00:00:00')]
```

Please check the base date!

Comment: Excel base date depends on the platform, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487

Comment: Thanks! it worked, never would have known those were offsets!

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.findall` with `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def parse(lis):
    h, m, s = map(int, lis)
    return timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)

tmp = s.str.zfill(6).str.findall(".{2}")
tmp.apply(parse)
```

Output:

```
0   04:34:30
1   04:36:39
2   04:36:05
3   04:33:29
4   04:33:30
5   04:36:04
6   04:36:01
7   04:33:32
8   04:36:02
9   04:35:05
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```